# Elementary OS running very slow

Tags: graphics, intel

I have a very old computer. It has 1 GB RAM, Celeron processor, and intel 82845g graphic card.

I can run XP smoothly. I wanted to run Linux on it. I installed Ubuntu, it ran but was very sluggish. I installed Lubuntu after that. It worked great but it wasn't looking that good. I heard that Elementary OS could run very well on my system from one of my friends.

I installed it and its also running very slow.

I am puzzled why it's very slow even though Linux systems are faster than Windows. XP runs without sluggishness in my system. I think it's the graphics drivers because of which Elementary OS is running slow. What do you think why it's running so slow even though I meet the minimum requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are experiencing lag due to the lack or performance of the laptop. It is old. I am not one to say, throw away a linux flavor because of this, but seeing how graphical Elementary is, you might be better off with a distribution tailored for slower older machines....
Have you tried Ubuntu Mate? That is using a GUI more for older machines, or perhaps LDE gui linux like Lubuntu.... They should perform much better on older hardware... 
Hope you find the perfect one... keeping on the debian / ubuntu structure..